# Flask API for uploading a video

Tags: flask, flask-reuploaded

I like to write an api that accept from the user a video via a post command. Any body can let me know how can I use Flask-Uploads for extensions mp4 or other video extensions?

Comment: https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Uploads/#upload-sets

Answer (score 1):

The version of `Flask-Uploaded` on PyPi is broken since February 2020.

You can use the drop in replacement: https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Reuploaded/

When you want a file extension, which is not contained in a pre-defined set, you just can create your own one.

e.g.

```
VIDEOS = tuple("mp4 mov")
```

and then configure `Flask-Reuploaded` as described in the documentation, i.e

```
videos = UploadSet('videos', VIDEOS)
```

If you do not want to use `Flask-Reuploaded`, there is a very good blog post by Miguel Grinberg explaining all the details - without using an upload extension:

https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/handling-file-uploads-with-flask

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: If you like the answer, please accept the answer and/or click the arrow up button. Thanks.